# Is there a way to define multiple rolling policies for a single log file in logback?

Tags: logback

I am trying to set up a logback configuration that creates an unzipped log file as the first roll, and from then on writes zipped files to a different directory.  I believe that the best way to do it is to create multiple rollingPolicy elements within a single appender.  Can anyone direct me to an example where someone has successfully done this?

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>test.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>tests.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>archives/tests.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>2</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```
<!-- Time and Size based: Roll every day and split big file in smaller peaces -->
<appender name="ROOT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_HOME}/root.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
           <fileNamePattern>${OTHER_HOME}/root-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
           <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
         <pattern>%date %-5level [%thread] - %mdc{loginName} - [%logger]- %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

- ${LOG_HOME} is your first diretory
- ${OTHER_HOME} is for you zipped files

Comment: That writes a single log file to ${LOG_HOME} though and then writes the zipped files to ${OTHER_HOME} correct?  I need to actually write the main log file and a single unzipped historic log to the same directory.  Everything after that needs to be zipped and stored in a separate directory.  I'm reasonably sure it isn't possible with logback.  I think I'm going to set up the logback config to just create the log and 2 rolled logs, and then write a script to zip the last log file when it shows up and move it to storage.