# How to define multiple rolling policies for a single log file in logback?

Tags: logback, filebeat, logrotate

I am facing same issue as mentioned in [Is there a way to define multiple rolling policies for a single log file in logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266125/is-there-a-way-to-define-multiple-rolling-policies-for-a-single-log-file-in-logb)
can any one know how to write multiple rolling policies which creates log like 
test.log,
test.1.log,
test.2.log.gz,
test.3.log.gz and so on... Here it first create normal log file and 2nd onward it create archive of same.
Later on this all log will be read by filebeat.

Also tried with two appender like

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>test.log</file>
            enter code here
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
              <fileNamePattern>archives/tests.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
              <minIndex>1</minIndex>
              <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
              <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
            <encoder>
              <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
          </appender>

        <appender name="FILETEST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>test.log</file>

            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
              <fileNamePattern>archives/tests.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
              <minIndex>2</minIndex>
              <maxIndex>7</maxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
              <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
            <encoder>
              <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
          </appender>

         <logger name="test-logger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
                <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
               <appender-ref ref="FILETEST"/>
        </logger>
```

This leads to generate the test.log, test.1.log, test.2.log.gz which I want but here it causes with it writes in both file test.log and in test.1.log at initial level, this again leads to data loss in rotation.